# creating table within table by pressing button

Tags: javascript

I currently have a table and in one of the `<td>`, I have input type of checkbox. where if user clicks on it, it will create different table.

```
<div style="padding-left:170px;">
<table width="80%" border="1" padding-left:50px>  
    <tr>  
        <td>  
            <table border="1" style="float:left"> 
                <th>Portal01</th> 
                <tr>  
                    <td style= "padding:12px;" align="left" >
                    <input type="test0" id = "test0" name="liveDiff"  onchange = "expandService()"> blah_0
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    blah_1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    blah_2
                    </td>
                </tr>  
           </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I have it set up where if user clicks on checkbox next to `blah_0`, it should create different table within this table. I am not sure if this is possible with JavaScript and if not, what would be alternate way to approach this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible.

```
function expandService(){
  document.getElementById('the_id_of_the_td_that_will_contain_the_new_table').innerHTML = 
    '<table><tr>...</tr></table>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `appendChild()`, here is an example:

```
function expandService(chkId, tblId, totalRows, totalCols){
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.id = tblId;
    var row, col, spn;
    for(var i=0; i<totalRows; i++){
        row = document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j=0; j<totalCols; j++){
            col = document.createElement('td');
            spn = document.createElement('span');
            spn.innerHTML = 'your-text';
            col.appendChild(spn);
            row.appendChild(col);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(row);
    }
    var chk = document.getElementById(chkId);
    // td is the parent of checkbox
    chk.parentNode.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

*Sample usage:*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test0" name="liveDiff" onchange="expandService(this.id, 'your-table-id', 5, 4)">
```

It creates a table with 5 rows and 4 columns.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with javascript.  One potential way to go is to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML).  Use jQuery or just `document.getElementByID` to select the element that corresponds to your cell and insert a table inside of it.  Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sk2Gj/2/) using your code as a base.

```
<div style="padding-left:170px;">
<table width="80%" border="1" padding-left:50px>  
    <tr>  
        <td>  
            <table border="1" style="float:left"> 
                <th>Portal01</th> 
                <tr>  
                    <td id="foo" style= "padding:12px;" align="left" >
                    <input type="test0" id = "test0" name="liveDiff"> blah_0
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    blah_1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    blah_2
                    </td>
                </tr>  
           </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>  ​
```

js:

```
var makeTable = function(contents){
    return '<table><td>' + contents + '</td></table>'
}

document.getElementById("test0").onchange = function(){
   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = makeTable("foo")
}
```

​